# Lightweight version control software on Linux

Tags: linux, version-control

I'm working with a shell account in a shared system and I would like to use some version control software for my bash scripts and config files.

It must works on Linux with no dependencies, just unpack it in my home dir. I don't need remote checkout, branching or other fancy tricks. I want to be able to commit my changes and restore them if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[fossil](http://fossil-scm.org).

Single binary.

No dependencies.

Version control.

Built in ticket tracker and wiki.

CLI and web interface.

Comment: Cool! I'm going try it out with darcs too.

Answer (score 5):

Try [Git](http://git-scm.com/).

Answer (score 1):

[Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/). You can just install it in a local directory and make sure that's in your PATH. It gives you a lot of power.

**Update for comment:**

Most hosting account have *way* more storage than you'll ever need (e.g. WebFaction gives you 10GB on a $10/mo account), so install Python locally. When you do the build/install simply add `--prefix=/home/you/local`. It will create local/bin/, local/lib/, etc. *Now* you have Python and then you can install Mercurial using your very own python.

If your account has little storage, or is missing critical build tools (like gcc, etc.), then you are using the wrong hosting.

Comment: Thanks but it needs Python which I don't have available.

Answer (score 0):

I just found [Darcs](http://wiki.darcs.net/Binaries) looking at previous questions. It fits perfectly to my needs.

Thanks Adam for your suggestion but Git depends on several packages which versions are not all available to me.

Answer (score 0):

I use Subversion.  Works fine for local access.

I also remotely check out my scripts to most of my shell accounts, I must say.  It's a really convenient way to make sure the setup of the different accounts stays aligned.